# Can I disable a git global setting per project?

Tags: git

I have a global git setting to convert https to ssh. For one particular project, I'd like to use https instead of ssh. Is it possible to disable the global setting for that one project?

edit:
I'm using the following setting: `url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadof=https://github.com/`

Comment: You can also have a local setting, which will override its global counterpart with `git config --local <your.setting> <its.value>`

Answer (score 1):

For *most* settings, local overrides global.

There are a very few settings where local and global are simply aggregated together, such as `remote.origin.fetch`.  You don't mention which setting you're using to do this conversion, but my guess is that it is the `url.<base>.insteadOf` setting.

I tried simply setting the same setting both globally and in the local repository, but having it replace itself with itself.  This failed!  (I'm actually doing the reverse, starting with ssh, switching to https globally, and trying to switch back locally.)

So, it seems the only thing to do is *selectively* replace URLs, and avoid replacing the one that you don't want replaced—or temporarily disable the global replacement for the duration of working with that one repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the setting in .git/config for the given repo.

Please see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config---local and https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config---worktree